# query condition comparing two fields

Tags: 8, database

i am having this query :

```
   $db = \Drupal::database();

  $exist_query= $db->select('user__roles', 'ur');
  $exist_query->fields('ur', ['entity_id']);
  $exist_query->condition('ur.entity_id','u.uid', '=');
  $exist_query->condition('ur.roles_target_id', $included_user_roles, 'IN');

  $not_exist_query= $db->select('user__roles', 'ur');
  $not_exist_query->fields('ur', ['entity_id']);
  $not_exist_query->condition('ur.entity_id','u.uid', '=');
  $not_exist_query->condition('ur.roles_target_id', $excluded_user_roles, 'IN');

  $query = $db->select('users_field_data', 'u');
  $query->fields('u', ['uid']);
  $query->condition('u.uid', 1, '>');
  if (!empty($param['login_value'])) {
    $query->condition('u.login', $logindate, '<');
    $query->condition('u.login', 0, '!=');
  }  
  $query->exists($exist_query);
  $query->notExists($not_exist_query);
  dpq($query);
```

the problem i am having is here

```
  $exist_query->condition('ur.entity_id','u.uid', '=');
```

it generates :

```
WHERE (ur.entity_id = 'u.uid')
```

when it should

```
WHERE (ur.entity_id = u.uid)
```

How can i solve this ?

The working request i am trying to achieve

```
SELECT u.uid AS uid
FROM
users_field_data u
WHERE (u.uid > '1') AND (u.login < '1586705658') AND (u.login != '0') AND (EXISTS (SELECT ur.entity_id AS entity_id
FROM
user__roles ur
WHERE (ur.entity_id = u.uid) AND (ur.roles_target_id IN ('admin_site')))) AND (NOT EXISTS (SELECT ur.entity_id AS entity_id
FROM
user__roles ur
WHERE (ur.entity_id = u.uid) AND (ur.roles_target_id IN ('membre_du_site'))))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add such a clause manually:

```
$not_exist_query->where('ur.entity_id = u.uid');
```